# how can i change the friends displayed so my app can be shared?

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i have a display that shows 6 random friends on facebook when using the app, however, what i would like to figure out is how to change the display, so that when the friend is clicked on, they are sent an invite to use the app.

Nothing flash, just some kind of notification to say something along the lines of 'Bob thinks you should use this app' and when clicked, they go to the app.

not sure if it will help, but here is the code i have to display friends of the user.

code:

```
<div class= "newboxbottom">
<h1>Why not share?</h1>
<?php
    $user = $facebook->getuser();

if ($user) {
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=first_name');

echo '<table>';
foreach (array_slice($friends["data"], 0, 6) as $value) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="pic">';
    echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture?type=normal"/>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div align="center">','<font color="white">','<div class="picName">'.$value["first_name"].'</div>','</font>','</div>';
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
</div>
```

many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: You might want to look a little into [Notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/)

Comment: thanks for the link, but i cant seem to figure out from that how i could implement it to the friends list to send a notification once clicked?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena has the right idea. You should probably take a closer look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/#impl

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the [Notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/#impl) that Anvesh mentioned in a comment.

You'll want to be careful with notifications and follow the recommended [best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/#best_practices). You don't want to send notifications to users who would not want them in the first place. You could get hit with negative feedback and get shut down by Facebook.

As for how to actually make the call? I haven't actually used this particular API method, but from what I can gather, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php
  $parameters = array( 
    'href' => ''
    'template' => ''
    'ref' => ''
  );
  try {
    $response = $facebook->api('<enter recipient user facebook id here>/notifications', 'post', $parameters);
  } catch (FacebookAPIException $e) {
    $echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Checkout the documentation on more information on the parameters you need to pass. Hope this helps.

Comment: i dont plan on sending random notifications, more like user to user invites

Comment: Gotcha, gotcha. Just wanted to give a heads up on the risk that Facebook will respond to negative feedback. Hope it will help you in designing and planning your user interaction to prevent it. Other than that, was I able to answer your question?

Comment: not sure yet, i appreciate the answer, but im having a break from coding for an hour or so. but once i try it i will comment again.

Comment: Just give it a try, it will work. Thanks for typing in more detailed answer @JayNCoke